# Auto-increment column in SQL Server does not always start at 1?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, auto-increment

I am using SqlServer 2005 and I have a table in which I have an auto incrementing column but for some reason the auto increment field does not start with 1 but with some random number like 21,91. Why does that happen?

Comment: Show your table definition and don't capitalize everything.

Comment: Why do you shout? You might [check documentation on dbcc checkident](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You either need to set the `Seed` for the column.... or if you had entered rows previously, you need to execute a `TRUNCATE TABLE` command on the table...

```
TRUNCATE TABLE XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

mssql is not using max(id) + 1 as identity like other databases. It is storing the last used id and is incrementing it.

You can reseed the identity:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('tablex', RESEED, 1)
```

or truncate the table, this is also deleting all the data:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablex
```

You can of course combine the identity reseed with the last value:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('tablex', RESEED, (SELECT max(id) + 1 FROM tablex))
```

But be aware of producing errors on reseeding the id due to conflicts, the auto increment id is unique!